# Sass compila en mi pc pero no en producción

Tags: reactjs, sass, nextjs

La pagina esta hecha con Next js y uso sass ^1.55.0 y @styled-jsx/plugin-sass ^4.0.2.

Al hacer `next build` pues me genera bien la pagina y todo y funciona con `next start` pero al hacer el next build en el servidor no compila el `<style jsx>` que esta escrito con sass en cada componente y me da errores así:

[image: Errores de Css en herramientas de desarrollador]

Tampoco me funciona en Vercel :(

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el error era que git no subia el archivo .babelrc.json, ya cargado en producción si compila bien.